# InvokeMethodOnNull in powershell when query a empty value

Tags: powershell

My powershell script will query and update the ldap attribute from ldap repository. But the attribute i wished to query/update is an empty field in ldap repository. As i know so far, the powershell cant accept empty value,so my script returned the following error message

```
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\deployment\test.ps1:67 char:17
+ ...               $f = $l.Attributes['String7'].GetValues('string')
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I put in `Set-StrictMode -Off` to accept the null value but it' seem like not work as expected 
Please refer to the following script

```
 foreach ($l in $r.Entries)
    {

       //some process over here 



        if($ID -eq "xxxxx")
        {


              $N = $l.Attributes['String11'].GetValues('string')

              if($N -eq "something here")
              {

                $f = $list.Attributes['String7'].GetValues('string')
                if($f -eq $null)
                 {
                    //update string7 attribute
                    $l.Attributes['String7'].SetValues("x") 
                 }

              } 
        }
```

`$r` will be my response from the ldap repository and the `String7` is empty by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with:

- PowerShell uses the `#` character as comment character, not `//`
- Your code is missing a final curly bracket `}`. (Using better indentation of the code, you could see the missing bracket quite easily)

By inserting a `try{..} catch{..}` construct, you would be able to overcome the error you're getting and update this attribute.
Something like:

```
foreach ($l in $r.Entries) {
    # some process over here 
    if($ID -eq "xxxxx") {
        $N = $l.Attributes['imString11'].GetValues('string')
        if($N -eq "something here") {
            try {
                $f = $list.Attributes['String7'].GetValues('string')
            }
            catch {}
            if(!$f) {
                # update string7 attribute
                $l.Attributes['String7'].SetValues("x") 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, u save my days. sry for the // instead of #. As i am new to powershell